# pROC - How to Get Confidence Intervals or Generate a Confusion Matrix

Tags: r, roc

I used the pROC package to do an ROC analysis.  It gave me the sensitivities, specificities, etc.

The journal is requesting 95% confidence intervals for every statistic provided.  I see I can do that in the epiR package, but I have to give it a confusion matrix.

How do I use the threshold provided from the pROC to get a confusion matrix?

Sample data and code:

```
library(pROC)
library(tibble)

data<-tribble(
  ~death, ~score,
  0, 0.132,
  1, 0.19, 
  0, 0.03,
  1, 0.131,
  0, 0.02
)

roc<-roc(data$death, data$score, smoothed = TRUE,
              ci=TRUE, ci.alpha=0.95, stratified=FALSE,
              plot=TRUE, auc.polygon=TRUE, max.auc.polygon=TRUE, grid=TRUE,
              print.auc=TRUE, show.thres=TRUE)

coords(roc, x="best", ret=c("threshold", "specificity", "sensitivity", "accuracy",
                                 "precision", "recall", "tpr", "ppv", "fpr"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a confusion matrix, you first need to assign predicted outcomes (predicted death, predicted survived) according to a threshold. The AUC is calculated over every possible threshold in your data. In my example I have arbitrarily selected the second lowest threshold to generate the example

```
#first assign a threshold
thres <- roc$thresholds[2]

#assign labels to your data according to the threshold
data$predicted_death <- data$score > thres

#convert to character vector to facilitate interpretation
data$predicted_death <-ifelse(data$predicted_death==1, "predicted_dead", "predicted_alive")
data$death <- ifelse(data$death==1, "dead", "alive")

#count the true positives, false positives, false negatives and true negatives in a confusion matrix using the R function table()
cm <- table(data$death, data$predicted_death)
```

I would advise choosing a threshold to optimise both of sensitivity and specificity, such as the youden index.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion matrix is a table with the the true|false positive|negative counts.

You can get it (albeit not as a table) with the coords function:

```
> coords(roc, x=0.0805, ret=c("tn", "tp", "fn", "fp"))
#           tn tp fn fp
# threshold  2  2  0  1
```

And you can get the confidence interval with the `ci.coords` function:

```
> ci.coords(roc, x=0.0805, ret=c("tn", "tp", "fn", "fp"))
# 95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
#        threshold tn.low tn.median tn.high tp.low tp.median tp.high fn.low
# 0.0805    0.0805      0         2       3      2         2       2      0
#        fn.median fn.high fp.low fp.median fp.high
# 0.0805         0       0      0         1       3
```

You will simply need to reorganize the data to a table that you see fit.

Comment: awesome - thanks!  will use this next time.